# Measuring time between 2 external interrupts

Tags: arduino

I want to measure the time between two signals that are not in phase and i am using arduino Uno. I have converted the 2 sinusoidal signals into square waves and i am feeding them on INT0 and INT1 respectively. To measure the lag between the two signals i want to measure the time between the rising edges or falling edges of the signals using interrupts. On receiving the first rising edge i want to start a timer, say timer 3, upon receiving the second rising edge i want to stop the timer. my problem is i cant find a library that will allow me to start and stop timer the 3 and use the value it has in store.how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about a whole number of microseconds between edges, you could create a global variable to store the time when the first interrupt is triggered `INT0LastTime=micros()`, and get the second interrupt to compare the 'time now' to the time of the first interrupt.`Lag=micros()- INT0LastTime;`

Comment: thanks let me try that, but does not the method micros() use interrupts , because I read some article which said if interrupts are enabled the method behaves normally only for a few micros then its behaviour goes out of hand, sorry if my question is too trivial or something I am new to this field of MCs

Comment: That's because the other interrupts may interfere with any code that relies on 'micros()' .  Say you had a while loop that checked 'micros()' on every loop and did something after x micros had passed; this risks inaccuracy because an interrupt may decide to do something just when your timer is due to expire, and your while loop has to wait. In this case we're using micros within an interrupt, so it's less of an issue (I think! I'm not an expert on interrupts).  regardless, Micros is only accurate to 4 ms,  assuming a 16mhz clock speed, lower clocks (e.g. internal clock) will be less accurate.